# How to create C3 chart from an api link?

Tags: c3

I tried to use [this example](http://c3js.org/samples/data_url.html) in order to create a C3 chart. But its using all the data in the api. I am using angularjs.

my data looks like this
[
No:1
Name:'abc'
Id:3
Value:34
]

here is my code

```
d3.json("http://api.mydata", function(data) {
    var convertedData = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
    convertedData.push([item.Id, item.Value]);
});
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto : '#chartContainer',
        data : {
            columns : [convertedData]
        },
         keys: {
            x: convertedData.ID,
            value: convertedData.Value
        }
    });
});
```

thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, you should probably [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The chart loads all data from the api and not the one i wanted to plot

Comment: And what have you tried in order to get the correct data?

Comment: i tired to convered the data from this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912813/ho-to-create-c3-chart-from-an-api-link

Answer (score 0):

The `data` field has to be populated with information about the axis as well. Here you have a functional example (sorry for the Spanish variables):

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#chart-" + value.siglas,
            data: {
                x: 'x',
                x_format: '%Y',
                columns: [
                    ['x', new Date('2011'), new Date('2012'), new Date('2013'), new Date('2014')],
                    ['Primera matrícula', value.tasas_2011.tasas1, value.tasas_2012.tasas1, value.tasas_2013.tasas1, value.tasas_2014.tasas1],
                    ['Segunda matrícula', value.tasas_2011.tasas2, value.tasas_2012.tasas2, value.tasas_2013.tasas2, value.tasas_2014.tasas2],
                    ['Tercera matrícula', value.tasas_2011.tasas3, value.tasas_2012.tasas3, value.tasas_2013.tasas3, value.tasas_2014.tasas3],
                    ['Cuarta matrícula', value.tasas_2011.tasas4, value.tasas_2012.tasas4, value.tasas_2013.tasas4, value.tasas_2014.tasas4],
                    ['Media nacional' + averageErrorFlag, average['tasas_2011'].toFixed(2), average['tasas_2012'].toFixed(2), average['tasas_2013'].toFixed(2), average['tasas_2014'].toFixed(2)]
                ]
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: "%Y" // https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In `data`, the format of the x axis and the values (in this graphic you have four variables and the x value) are included. You can also format the x axis with the `axis` key.